# SPSS compute cases in different variables

Tags: syntax, spss

I am currently using SPSS to process my data.
eg. I have data like

V1       V2      V3

258      235

236      567

123      987

576      234

678      456

for the values of V3, I wanna compute the case of V1 minus the former case of V2 
they are 236-235, 123-567, 576-987, 678-234

Because I have more than one million data , and I wanna do a loop compute

so how should I write in Syntax?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. Does not `COMPUTE C12 = V1 - V2.` do what you want, or are you asking something else?

Comment: i think my question is obscured,

Comment: C11 and C12 are value for variable V1, C21 and C22 are values for V2, the value for V3 is X, X = C12-C21, how can i write Syntax, because I have more than one million records, i wanna do a loop computation, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics automatically loops over the cases.  You just need to write the compute statement.  If you meant the previous case by "former case of V2", see the LAG function.

Comment: I tried LAG, it doesnt seem helpful, i thought there is something like

Comment: sth like "compute V3=V1(+1)-V2."BUT I forgot the correct statment, the outputs keeps telling me Error #4023 An expression contains a string of characters followed by a left parenthesis, indicating that the string of characters is a function or vector name, but the characters do not match any existing function or vector.

Comment: @user3278216 JKP is correct here, what you want from your example is `COMPUTE V3 = V1 - LAG(V2).` Your sentences are very difficult to follow, but giving the snippet of data this accomplishes what you ask for.